# Bending with end objects

Tags: parent

I am a very new Blender user.  I have made an object that I would like to bend, but I would like the child objects on both ends to be unaffected by the deform.  I have tried using a simple deform and also adding bones, but in either case, the end objects seem to always deformed and I don't want them to be.  I just want them to remain attached to the middle object as it deforms.  Can anyone give me a hint at how I accomplish this?

[image: Ubent object]

[[image: Using bones[2]]

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have done the cable with a beveled curve, and hook their first and last vertices to the connection sockets.

For a mesh, bones are a good idea, you can use b-bones for more flexibility: Create your bone chain, display as *B-Bones*, segment the bones (except the top one), parent *With Automatic Weight*, correct the weight paint so that top and bottom won't deform, bend the bones. It's a bit tedious to bend because of the parent/child chain, you could improve that but if it's not for animation, no need to create *IK* or *Spline IK*.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much!  I went with this option and it seems to be working well!

Answer (score 0):

If your are using bones, you need to use constraints 
Copy location and copy rotation// Target is the Armature and Bone is the the closest to the end

[image]

Hope that helps